# Switch statement won't break

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

I'm in the beginning of Java 7 Software design learning switch() and do...while () and what not.

When I compile and run the program in Intelli J IDEA 13, it compiles and runs fine but nothing will break when the statements are complete.

For example, when the program is run, on case 2, when I enter -1 after I input 3 grades (90, 90, 90, -1) it gives me the average (270) but then it repeats...

It should break and go back to the beginning of the switch menu. Even when I enter 3 at the menu, it just displays "No Code Here... " to infinity, even with a break statement (even though break statements are outdated).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingPlatform {
public static void main(String[] args) {   

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to set percentage of total for new grades, 2 to enter new      grades, 3 to get average, and 4 to quit: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    do {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter percent to multiply by: ");
                double percent = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("You entered " + percent);
                break;
            case 2:
                int total;
                int gradeCounter;
                int grade;
                double average;
                total = 0;
                gradeCounter = 0;

                System.out.println("Enter grade or -1 to quit: ");
                grade = input.nextInt();

                while (grade != -1) {
                    total = total + grade;
                    gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
                    System.out.println("Enter grade or -1 to quit: ");
                    grade = input.nextInt();
                }
                if (gradeCounter != 0) {
                    average = (double) total / gradeCounter;

                    System.out.printf("\nTotal of the %d grades is %d\n", gradeCounter, total);
                    System.out.printf("Class average is %.2f\n", average);
                } else
                    System.out.println("No grades were entered.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("No code here yet....");
                break;

        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}
}
```

Comment: there are 2 issues with you code, 1) your while loop doesn't take the  input, 2) you need to enter 4 to break the loop not -1

Comment: Are we talking about case 2 or the whole program, Mehul Rathod?

Comment: @MehulRathod: -1 is what you enter to get out of the inner loop, the one inside case 2. 4 is entered to get out of the outer loop, which is where is issue was (since he wasn't giving the option to choose again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are taking input once, then looping while input is not 4. Since the input never changes, that's forever.

The `break` inside the switch just jumps out of the `switch`. Then you continue your loop.

Put these lines:

```
System.out.println("Enter 1 to set percentage of total for new grades, 2 to enter new      grades, 3 to get average, and 4 to quit: ");
choice = input.nextInt();
```

Inside the `do` loop, not outside it. Then you will ask for new input every time you loop.

You'll have to declare `choice` outside the loop though, since you reference it in the `while` at the bottom.

Put this line above the `do` loop:

```
int choice;
```

Comment: What should I do about the "while ( choice !=4 );" because I"m getting java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable choice
  location: class TestingPlatform

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited my answer!

Comment: My God... You are a savior Blorgbeard! Thank you for taking the time to help me out with the infinite loop problem!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason it will always loop again and hit the switch again is because you are never changing the value of `choice` again. The `break` statement is only breaking out of the `switch` statement, not the loop itself. After you finish the `switch` you need to ask the user again if they want to pick another option or if they want to enter four to quit.

`break` statements will only break out of the inner most...group? Statement? I'm not sure what the correct word would be, but it only will break out one level, not all the way.

Just for the sake of saying it, always remember that you have four parts of a loop: Initialization, Condition, Body, and Changer.

Initialization: where the variables IN THE CONDITION are assigned their initial values; this could happen inside the loop in the case of a `do...while();` and there could be multiple locations

Condition: the part that decides if your loop will continue or not

Body: the code that is being looped over and over

Changer: (this is the one most often missed, I've noticed) a spot, or spots, where variables IN YOUR CONDITION are having their values changed; there could be multiple locations and multiple variables being affected

Comment: Ah, so as Blorgbeard said, put the switch statement inside the do instead of outside of it so when the break statement happens, it will go back to the menu. Thanks for the advise Josh Braun!

Comment: Ya, but in your code above you had the location of your `switch` in the correct location. The problem was that you were never asking for another choice from the user. So after the `switch` (because that's where the choices are) you need to ask again so when your program checks to see if it needs to continue, `choice` has been changed and has a possibility to make the condition `false` (look at my in my post). Also, I'm assuming it was a typo, 270 isn't the average of three 90s...it should be 90.